# Shell - Echo in loop return strange

Tags: windows, postgresql, shell, sh

Im new with shell, im trying to get database name and loop it to do something

```sh
#!/bin/sh

DBLIST=`"C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/bin/psql" -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -q -t -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false AND datname IN('beta_irian','beta_kupang','beta_makassar')"`

for d in $DBLIST
do
    echo "DB NAME = $d HALO X"
done
```

But im stuck here,, the result i got is not what i wanted.

[image: here is the result]

the result what i wanted is

```
DB NAME = beta_kupang HALO X
DB NAME = beta_irian HALO X
DB NAME = beta_makassar HALO X
```

IDK why it only work in last loop

Comment: I don't see how you possibly can get **this** output, even in the case that the lines produced by psql would contain carriage return characters. After all the `echo` explicitly prints a _HALO X_ at the end, so each line being printed should have a _DB NAME_ and at the end a _HALO X_. I suggest that you run the code using `set -x`, to find out what's going on here.

Comment: @user1934428 I tried -x and it show "HALO X'DB NAME = beta_irian" idk what's happening here. but in the last loop it show normally "echo 'DB NAME = beta_kupang HALO X'" [here is the pic](https://ibb.co/kxRvsvd)